# Symfony2 admin panel (for users) - is it good idea to use SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I would like to ask about some advices, how to use Symfony2 SonataAdminBundle.
I am going to prepare 'kind of bigger application', bigger in meaning that user will have a lot to do after authentication.
FOS/UserBundle is awesome and I need to prepare some forms to edit a tables.
I do not know when/if should I try to extend and change SonataAdminBundle to handle different user type, or based everything on Symfony Forms and prepare my own "admin panel for user" with using forms, etc.

How do you make this decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SonataAdminBundle` is very flexible. You can define your own admin class and CRUD controller, so that the user will be able to perform any sort of administration tasks. The bundle (and Symfony itself) has been specifically designed for "bigger" applications, so why shouldn't you take advantage of it?